# How to change the text of the ios "more" button into the version in my language?

Tags: ios, localization, uitabbar

in my ios app i have a tabbar containing a lot of button. Some of them are after the "More" button. There's a way to change the text of the "more" button to "altro" that is "more" in my language?

Comment: You want to change the text to the UIButton title?

Comment: yes, but the button is automatically generated by the apple tabbar system so i guess not to have direct control.. Maybe it is a localization problem.

Comment: are you talking about the `TabBarItem`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the properties title and image of a `UITabBarItem` provided by the system can not be changed, as the [documentation says](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITabBarItem/initWithTabBarSystemItem:tag:):

> **Discussion**
>
> This method returns a system-supplied tab bar item. The title and image properties of the returned item cannot be changed later.

This value be will automatically localized to the correct language by the operating system. If you need to change this you will have to create the item, and its functionality, by yourself.

Comment: what do you mean by "automatically localized"? I live in Italy, programming on an italian version mac os, i'm developing on an italian iphone/ipad, but still my button is english localized for is "more" instead of "altro". Who tells the button to display in english?

Comment: that's because you haven't implement the localization yet, you has to include the languages that you want to your app and localize the resources, take a look to this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial

Comment: if you take a look on your project properties you will see that it is only in english

Comment: done! thank you! In xcode 4.6, it was enough to add the language "Italian" into the "localization" screen of my project.